# Python xgboost: kernel died

Tags: python, xgboost

My Jupyter notebook's python kernel keeps dying. I have run all of the following code successfully before. Presently, there are issues. First, I will show you the code chunk that I am able to run successfully:

```
import xgboost as xgb
xgtrain = xgb.DMatrix(data = X_train_sub.values, label = Y_train.values)       # create dense matrix of training values
xgtest  = xgb.DMatrix(data = X_test_sub.values,  label = Y_test.values)        # create dense matrix of test values
param   = {'max_depth':2, 'eta':1, 'silent':1, 'objective':'binary:logistic'}  # specify parameters via map
```

where my data is small:

```
X_train_imp_sub.shape
(1365, 18)
```

however, my notebook's kernel keeps dying on this chunk:

```
xgmodel = xgb.train(param,  xgtrain, num_boost_round = 2)                      # train the model
predictions = xgmodel.predict(xgtest)                                          # make prediction
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score                                   
accuracy = accuracy_score(y_true = Y_test, 
                          y_pred = predictions.round(), 
                          normalize = True) # If False, return # of correctly classified samples. Else, return fraction of correctly classified samples
print("Accuracy: %.2f%%" % (accuracy * 100.0))
```

When I break it apart and run line-by-line, the kernel appears to die on the `xgb.train()` line.

The data is small. The xgboost parameters should be conservative (i.e. `num_boost_round = 2`, `max_depth:2`, `eta:1` and not computationally expensive. Not sure what is going on.

As stated before, I have been able to run both chunks successfully before. I have shut down all other notebooks and restarted my computer without luck. I am launching `jupyter` through Anaconda Navigator on a Macbook Pro.

-- UPDATE --
When I selected a cell beneath my `xgboost` training cell, then selected: `Cells` --> `Run All Above`, the kernel would always die on the `xgboost` training line. This happened ~40-50 times in a row. I tried that many times because I was making changes to the code, thinking I would resolve the `xgboost` issue later.

Later on, I ran the same cells one-by-one and the `xgboost` completed fine on the first time I tried this and every time after. I do not know why this happens but it would be nice to know.

Comment: Could you identify which command causes the kernel collapse? The last code cell is very diverse. Does it die in training, in prediction or in accurace calculation?

Comment: @MykhailoLisovyi it varies. In my notebook, I broke the cell up in an attempt to ascertain the offending code. However, there is no line that consistently causes failure. Sometimes it fails at line 1, sometimes at line 1+t

Comment: I am having the exact same problem, how did you solve this issue? It would be great if you could tell me the solution

Answer (score 24):

I was having a similar problem. This fixed it for me.

```
import os
os.environ['KMP_DUPLICATE_LIB_OK']='True'
from xgboost import XGBClassifier
```

Comment: Great solution, this is a widespread issue with xgboost and matplotlib

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue. The stupid thing is it was working fine, just suddenly decided it wants to go crazy! I tried @PandaRocks's solution. it did not work. I tried restarting stuff. 
even saw some stuff about a library file removal [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/43042/26630).

finally ended up solving it by reinstalling the XGBoost using `conda` as explained [here](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/xgboost):

```
$ conda install -c conda-forge xgboost
```

Comment: That worked for me in 2022, with lightgbm==3.3.2, python==3.9. It seems we better use conda to install packages instead of pip...

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have 'Inf' values in the data. This is often the case when using 'pct_change()'. xgBoost crashes the kernel when using Inf values.

Answer (score 0):

None of the solutions above work for me.

I've tried:

- deleting libiomp5.dylib
- import os
  os.environ['KMP_DUPLICATE_LIB_OK']='True'
  from xgboost import XGBClassifier
- updating libomp using `brew install libomp`

My code fails at the following line:

```
# Create the XGBoost DMatrix
dtrain = xgb.dask.DaskDMatrix(client, X_train, y_train)
```

I'm working on a 2020Macbook Pro, OS11.3.1, Python 3.9.

Any other suggestions very welcome!

Comment: I have the same macbook pro with OS 11.2.1 and Python v3.7. And the conda installation fixed it for me. I'd recommend downgrading python version if you haven't already fixed it another way.

Comment: Thanks @TCArlen -- what do you mean with the conda installation? do you mean Omid S.'s answer?

Comment: Yes that’s right. Uninstall xgboost via pip then install it according to Omid S.’s answer