# XGBoost crashing kernel in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, kernel, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, xgboost

I don't know how to make the `XGBoost` classifier work. I am running the code below on Jupyter notebook, and it always generates this message *"The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically."*

```
from xgboost import XGBClassifier
model = XGBClassifier()
model.fit(X, y)
```

There is no problem with importing the `XGBClassifier`, but it crashes upon fitting it to my data. `X` is a `502` by 33 all-numeric dataframe, `y` is the set of 0 or 1 labels for each row. 
Does anyone know what could be the problem here? I downloaded the newest version of `XGBoost` through `pip3` install, and also through `Conda` install.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51164771/python-xgboost-kernel-died ?

Answer (score 21):

I was having similar problem. I solved it by installing an older version 0.80.

```
pip install xgboost==0.80
```

Comment: Евгений , спасибо вам огромное! I've been trying to solve this issue for a few days in a row. I've even decided to move from my laptop's Jupyter to the Kaggle's one with the powerful GPU on it. Then I googled again and came across this answer which really solved my problem! Thanks a loooot!

Comment: I always love it when a _newer_ version of a library has some _critical_ error. Worked for me, thanks!

Comment: This is so far the best solution, after wasting nearly 3 hours how to install xgboost from source

Answer (score 2):

```
import os
os.environ['KMP_DUPLICATE_LIB_OK']='True'
from xgboost import XGBClassifier
model = XGBClassifier()
model.fit(X, y)
```