# XGBOOST killing Jupyter Notebook Kernel

Tags: python, machine-learning, jupyter-notebook, xgboost

I'm currently trying to run an XGBOOST model locally on Jupyter notebook. I have a dataset with shape (68799, 85). The idea is to use Optuna to conduct hyperparameter tuning. However, the kernel on Jupyter notebook dies with the message `The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically.`

The notebook dies when I convert my train, test and validation sets to the `DMatrix` data type before any model fitting/tuning begins:

```
features = df.drop(["Target"], axis = 1) # X
target = df["Target"] # Y
    
train_ratio = 0.8
val_ratio = 0.1
test_ratio = 0.1

# Creating train and test sets
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(features,
                                                    target,
                                                    test_size = 1 - train_ratio,
                                                    random_state = 42)

# Creating validation set
X_val, X_test, y_val, y_test = train_test_split(X_test,
                                                y_test,
                                                test_size = test_ratio/(test_ratio + val_ratio),
                                                random_state = 42) 
    
# Converting to DMatrix
    
d_train = xgb.DMatrix(X_train,
                          label = y_train)
    
d_test = xgb.DMatrix(X_test,
                         label = y_test)
    
d_val = xgb.DMatrix(X_val,
                        label = y_val)
```

I will eventually provision EC2 resources on AWS but I wanted to check whether Jupyter is crashing because I have a large dataset or whether there is some underlying issues with Jupyter or even my machine:

`Processor: 2.6 GHz 6-Core Intel Core i7`

`Memory: 16 GB 2667 MHz DDR4`

`Graphics: AMD Radeon Pro 5300M 4 GB Intel UHD Graphics 630 1536 MB`

Has anyone come across such an issue before? It just seems odd that the kernel dies before the model is even training.

Comment: You should get a more meaningful error message by running your code in a python shell (outside jupyter) that should provide a real error message.

Answer (score 2):

I tried absolutely everything on every webpage that discusses this issue. The only thing that worked for me was downgrading to a previous xgboost version. Here's what I did (in my MacOS terminal) that worked:

```
pip uninstall xgboost
pip install xgboost==0.80
```

Found the answer above on this post (big thanks to Евгений Куприков who answered it): [XGBoost crashing kernel in jupyter notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51768403/xgboost-crashing-kernel-in-jupyter-notebook)